# How to check String "green" is valid color or not in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, colors

I have scenario where user provide color name. For that I first need to check user provided color name is valid or not using jquery.

For example user can provide values orange, ornge typo.

How to check.

Any help will be best for me.

Comment: AFAIK, they get changed to rgba or hex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following method to validate css color

1. Create a temporary element
2. Set any color using `css('backgroundColor', 'white')`
3. After apply with the input value as `backgroundColor` using d.css('backgroundColor', this.value);
4. Check the the color is changed or entered value is same that we are initially set, in that case it's a valid color

```js
$('#input').keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.trim()) {
    var d = $('<span/>')
      .css('backgroundColor', 'white')
      .css('backgroundColor', this.value);
    $('#op').html(this.value + (d.css('backgroundColor') == '' && this.value + (d.css('backgroundColor') != 'white' && d.css('backgroundColor') != 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') || /^white$/i.test(this.value) ? ' is valid' : ' is not valid'));
  } else
    $('#op').empty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">

<div id="op"></div>
```

Comment: var d = $('#testelement')
             .css('backgroundColor', 'white')
             .css('backgroundColor',  d["displayColor"]);
        var coloris =   (d.css('backgroundColor') != 'white' && d.css('backgroundColor') != 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' || this.value == 'white' ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
      why this is not working for string.

Comment: @SohamShetty : I couldn't get you

Comment: I have used some part of your code which is correct but its not working for me you are taking values from input field that is not required for me as I'm reading excel file. variable d["displayColor"] has the color values which I need to check

Comment: var d = $('#testelement')
             .css('backgroundColor', 'white')
             .css('backgroundColor',  d["displayColor"]);
        var coloris =   (d.css('backgroundColor') != 'white' && d.css('backgroundColor') != 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' || d["displayColor"] == 'white' ? 'valid' : 'invalid');

Comment: @SohamShetty : various errors in that http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/115xkm3g/2/

Comment: @ Pranav thanks it worked. but for white color also it should give valid color.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89306/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-soham-shetty).

Answer (score 2):

You can set that color to any hidden test element(default color white) on page. then retrieve the color property from that element. if its other than white, then color is valid. else it is not.

```
$('#testelement').css('background-color', colorstring);
var coloris = !(/\d/.test(colorstring)) && (colorstring == "white" || $('#testelement').css('background-color') != "rgb(255, 255, 255)")   ? "valid" : "invalid";
alert(colorstring +' is '+ coloris );
```

Comment: What if without adding textelement,

Comment: $('#testelement').css('background-color', colorstring); cant do without this and also I have map of colors like d["color']

Comment: @SohamShetty: you can also create temporary element instead. also you can use d["color'] instead of colorstring everywhere to make this work.

Comment: it seems like for int value 12,35 is also valid color according to your code

Comment: You r rocker @MilindAnantwar

Comment: @SohamShetty: glad it helps :)

Comment: please share jsfiddle because it is not working for all scenario

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89254/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-soham-shetty).