# How do you tell if fillStyle has been assigned an illegal color?

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors

Suppose someone attempts to assign as follows

`var c = document.getElementById("canvasID");
var g = c.getContext("2d");
g.fillStyle = "pukeYellow";  //illegal color`

Can this be detected? Does `g.fillStyle` become some sentinel value?

Imagine you are writing a web app that asks a user for a named color and then displays the color.  How can we tell the user he made a boo-boo?

Comment: It will return a hex of that color otherwise it will fill it with black.

Comment: Why not just test it? Maybe it turns black or white which you could detect. Maybe you can check the input, i mean rgb is usually between 0 and 255 with optional opacity from 0 to 1. If you are using hex its from 00 to ff 3-4 times, eg #RRGGBB[AA] .. if an invalid input is detected just write an error message describing the problem

Comment: Can't you just validate the user input against the [list of all valid colors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color?v=example#Formal_syntax)?

Comment: @le_m  I was hoping not to have to do this, but is is probably the only workable solution.

Comment: What is so illegal about `pukeYellow`?  Please state the law, regulation or bylaw that makes it so.  Perhaps you mean invalid?

Comment: not a recognized color.  Try using it in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the HTML Canvas 2D Context specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-fillstyle):

> **8 Fill and stroke styles**
>
> If the value is a string but cannot be parsed as a CSS  value, or is neither a string, a CanvasGradient, nor a CanvasPattern, then **it must be ignored**, and the attribute must **retain its previous value**.

I assume you are only interested in valid CSS color values [as defined here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color). You have at least three options to validate CSS color values:

- Via comparing `context.fillStyle` before and after assignment, if both are equal the user either supplied an identical or an invalid color value
- Via manual validation:

  ```
  const colors = new Set(["aliceblue", "antiquewhite", "aqua", "aquamarine", "azure", "beige", "bisque", "black", "blanchedalmond", "blue", "blueviolet", "brown", "burlywood", "cadetblue", "chartreuse", "chocolate", "coral", "cornflowerblue", "cornsilk", "crimson", "cyan", "darkblue", "darkcyan", "darkgoldenrod", "darkgray", "darkgreen", "darkgrey", "darkkhaki", "darkmagenta", "darkolivegreen", "darkorange", "darkorchid", "darkred", "darksalmon", "darkseagreen", "darkslateblue", "darkslategray", "darkslategrey", "darkturquoise", "darkviolet", "deeppink", "deepskyblue", "dimgray", "dimgrey", "dodgerblue", "firebrick", "floralwhite", "forestgreen", "fuchsia", "gainsboro", "ghostwhite", "gold", "goldenrod", "gray", "green", "greenyellow", "grey", "honeydew", "hotpink", "indianred", "indigo", "ivory", "khaki", "lavender", "lavenderblush", "lawngreen", "lemonchiffon", "lightblue", "lightcoral", "lightcyan", "lightgoldenrodyellow", "lightgray", "lightgreen", "lightgrey", "lightpink", "lightsalmon", "lightseagreen", "lightskyblue", "lightslategray", "lightslategrey", "lightsteelblue", "lightyellow", "lime", "limegreen", "linen", "magenta", "maroon", "mediumaquamarine", "mediumblue", "mediumorchid", "mediumpurple", "mediumseagreen", "mediumslateblue", "mediumspringgreen", "mediumturquoise", "mediumvioletred", "midnightblue", "mintcream", "mistyrose", "moccasin", "navajowhite", "navy", "oldlace", "olive", "olivedrab", "orange", "orangered", "orchid", "palegoldenrod", "palegreen", "paleturquoise", "palevioletred", "papayawhip", "peachpuff", "peru", "pink", "plum", "powderblue", "purple", "rebeccapurple", "red", "rosybrown", "royalblue", "saddlebrown", "salmon", "sandybrown", "seagreen", "seashell", "sienna", "silver", "skyblue", "slateblue", "slategray", "slategrey", "snow", "springgreen", "steelblue", "tan", "teal", "thistle", "tomato", "turquoise", "violet", "wheat", "white", "whitesmoke", "yellow", "yellowgreen"]);
  colors.has(input.toLowerCase());
  ```
- Via [setting and checking the style of a temporary HTMLElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494794/how-to-check-string-green-is-valid-color-or-not-in-jquery).

I recommend one of the first two solutions.

Comment: @Akxe Yup, that is point one on my list of possible solutions. Drawback: It doesn't allow to distinguish between colors that are invalid or just identical to the previously set color without additional logic

Answer (score 0):

Experimentation reveals this. If you assign an illegal color, the assignment simply fails.   The graphics context's state is unchanged. JavaScript, as seems typical of its manner, just ignores your mistake and forges on.  You can also try the color in [this web app](http://www2.ncssm.edu/~morrison/currentClasses/352/pages/named.html).  The app will also display colors associated with hex codes if you precede the hex code with a #.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid color string will be interpreted as last valid color (or `#000000`, black).

This snipet should be enought for most usecases.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")
context.fillStyle = "#ff0000"
console.log(testColor("yellow"))
console.log(testColor("pukeYellow"))
console.log(testColor("red"))
console.log(context.fillStyle)

function testColor(color){
    var tmp = context.fillStyle
    context.fillStyle = color
    var result = context.fillStyle == tmp
    if(result){
        var tmp2 = tmp == '#ffffff' ? '#000000' : '#ffffff'
        context.fillStyle = tmp2
        context.fillStyle = color
        result = (context.fillStyle+'') == (tmp2+'')
    }
    context.fillStyle = tmp
    return !result
}
```

**Warning: Tested only on chrome!**